# " Could not find API definition for name "JDO"" when launched through jar

Tags: java, spring, maven, hive, datanucleus

So when I try to connect to my hive metastore I'm getting this exception

```
javax.jdo.JDOFatalInternalException: Unexpected exception caught.
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.invokeGetPersistenceManagerFactoryOnImplementation(JDOHelper.java:1193)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOHelper.java:808)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOHelper.java:701)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.getPMF(ObjectStore.java:412)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.getPersistenceManager(ObjectStore.java:441)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.initialize(ObjectStore.java:336)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.setConf(ObjectStore.java:292)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:73)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:133)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RawStoreProxy.<init>(RawStoreProxy.java:60)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RawStoreProxy.getProxy(RawStoreProxy.java:69)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.newRawStore(HiveMetaStore.java:681)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.getMS(HiveMetaStore.java:659)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.createDefaultDB(HiveMetaStore.java:708)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.init(HiveMetaStore.java:507)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.<init>(RetryingHMSHandler.java:78)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.getProxy(RetryingHMSHandler.java:84)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.newRetryingHMSHandler(HiveMetaStore.java:6286)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.<init>(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:207)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.<init>(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:187)
    at com.bouygtel.jupiter.dic.catalogue.AspirationMetastore.aspirer(AspirationMetastore.java:146)
    at com.bouygtel.jupiter.dic.integration.adaptateurs.AdaptateurUpdate.lambda$updateDatabase$0(AdaptateurUpdate.java:68)
    at com.bouygtel.commun.summer.socle.coeur.threads.SummerExecutorServiceFactory$3.run(SummerExecutorServiceFactory.java:160)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper$16.run(JDOHelper.java:1965)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.invoke(JDOHelper.java:1960)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.invokeGetPersistenceManagerFactoryOnImplementation(JDOHelper.java:1166)
    ... 25 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.datanucleus.exceptions.NucleusUserException: Error : Could not find API definition for name "JDO". Perhaps you dont have the requisite datanucleus-api-XXX jar in the CLASSPATH?
    at org.datanucleus.api.ApiAdapterFactory.getApiAdapter(ApiAdapterFactory.java:93)
    at org.datanucleus.AbstractNucleusContext.<init>(AbstractNucleusContext.java:118)
    at org.datanucleus.PersistenceNucleusContextImpl.<init>(PersistenceNucleusContextImpl.java:170)
    at org.datanucleus.PersistenceNucleusContextImpl.<init>(PersistenceNucleusContextImpl.java:159)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.<init>(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:436)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.createPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:314)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:223)
    ... 33 common frames omitted
```

But I have this in my pom.xml

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
<artifactId>datanucleus-api-jdo</artifactId>
<version>5.0.3</version>
</dependency>
```

The weird thing is that this only happens when I use my code through the jar, when I run it from eclipse, the thing works perfectly.
I double checked through "jar tf" and the jar that I run does contain the "datanucleus-api-jdo-5.0.3.jar".

I've searched for conflicts in my dependency hierarchy and there is one dependency that also use an older version of the "datanucleus-api-jdo", but it's omitted for conflict according to eclipse and excluding it does not solve the problem

Not sure if that helps but the run configuration within eclipse is "clean package spring-boot:run".

Any ideas of what is causing this?
If you think any information is missing please ask

Comment: What is `the jar that I run does contains the "datanucleus-api-jdo"`???

Comment: The jar file that gives me the exception mentionned above, I'm not sure I understood the question

Comment: It's the jar that eclipse generate when I build the project

Comment: so debug this jar and what is in it! That is where you'll find your answer ...

Comment: Did you Solved this Issue ?